# Um serviço que roda todos os dias em background no android

Tags: android, services, background, android-alarmmanager

Boa tarde !
   Talvez a minha pergunta não se encaixe perfeitamente nos critérios por ser mais uma dúvida se "é possive ou não é possivel".
   Eis o problema:
   Quero criar um app no seguinte cenário: ele marcará quanto tempo a tela do celular fica desligada seguidamente, após um determinado horario mesmo que o app em questão não esteja ativo.
   Segue cenário para melhor compreensão: O app está instalado no celular, porém está no estado Destroy, dentro do app eu configurei para que ele contasse a partir das 10 hrs da noite apenas... então, mesmo com o app "não ativo" eu quero que todos os dias, após as 22hrs ele conte quanto tempo a tela do celular não é ligada(quanto tempo a pessoa ficou sem mexer no celular) onde eu capturaria esse tempo e armazenaria para fins estatisticos, em resumo seria como uma tarefa do app que rodasse autonmamente, quase como o SO Android, tudo isso pq quero criar um app que tente advinhar quanto tempo o usuário tem dormido, por isso a questão da hora inicial, onde ele configura "normalmente eu durmo por esse horario", então se a tela estiver desligada por mais de 2hrs após esse horario o app irá entender que o usuário está dormindo.

Por favor me respondam se isso é possivel para que eu acabe não injetando tempo em um projeto que não pode ser concluido por ser loucura demais rsrs.
Desde já agradeço a comunidade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá pra fazer utilizando um service.

@https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841929/1615055
Use o AlarmManager pra configurar qual horário o serviço deve iniciar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22); // ou horário configurado pelo usuário
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
        new Intent(context, Sono.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent );
```

Obs.: Vc precisaria criar uma lógica pra finalizar o serviço depois.

@https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478013/1615055
No seu Service OnStart() registre para receber os eventos de ScreenOn e ScreenOff

```
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, screenStateFilter);
```

Lembre de desregistrar no Service OnDestroy()

```
unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
```

Toda vez que o evento for recebido, vc pode guardar em um banco de dados o timestamp e depois extrair a quantidade de tempo que a tela ficou desligada (diferença entre cada SCREEN_OFF e SCREEN_ON).

Lembrando que o Android pode matar seu serviço para liberar memoria, então a contagem ficaria errada. Para diminuir a change disso acontecer, você poderia criar uma notificação persistente enquanto o serviço estivesse rodando.